# How to find usage of an API method in all libraries in classpath?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, I can easily find out where is a method used in all jars in the classpath. This is very useful because I am using a library whose API is not well documented. I always need to find out how an API method is used by the library itself.

But in IntelliJ, I can only find the usage in the source code of my own project. Is it possible to do it in all jar files in my classpath? How? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ctrl-alt-shift-f7</kbd> to adjust the scope of your find-usages search to `Project and libraries`.

In addition to your project files, it will search everything under *External Libraries*  in your project pane - i.e. maven dependencies and the jdk.

However, for some reason I can't see any project libraries or global libraries under *External Libraries*, and as such they seem to be excluded from this search...

Comment: It seems should work, but I found nothing. Meanwhile, I open the same project with Eclipse and search for the same method, and got a lot of matches.

Comment: Did u try restarting IntelliJ ? Are the libraries configured to be used in your project? And what happens if you try it on, say, `String.concat` ?

Comment: I have restarted IntelliJ. My libraries are in the dependencies list of the module. However, they are not jar files but global libraries (ie. user libraries in Eclipse) - maybe that's why?

Comment: Yes that seems to be correct. Whatever is under *External Libraries* seems to be searched, but this doesnt include project libs.

Comment: On OSX it's cmd-alt-shift-f7.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a bug in IDEA that Find Usages doesn't search under module libraries. See [my comment here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99773#comment=27-576489) for the details and vote for the issue to get it fixed sooner.